# Azure Function App Blob Trigger yields unexpected Egress / Bandwidth

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App which is restricted to just users of my organisation using AAD.  It's not a high volume app: it's had only 104 unique users in the last week, 302 sessions and 3k page views.  The largest blob it serves is 5kb.  (That would be approx 15Mb using back-of-napkin tactics over the week for that largest file: 3k page views, if each and every page view used it, which isn't the case)

However, in the past week, the egress chart for the storage account my function app uses looks like this... just over 2Gb of blob egress.  [image]

**The strange thing about it is that the blob egress doesn't seem to correlate to the other usage patterns of the app:** note the fairly constant blob egress pattern, compared to the (more normal) up and down pattern of users.

[image]

This got me thinking:  I have a few background processes for reporting, one of which is a daily timer function - it produces a daily report and puts it into blob storage, which then gets emailed to a few users.... **so my question is**: is the blob trigger function which picks up the report file somehow causing all this outbound blob traffic?  [Note, it does nothing special: takes the injected Stream and attaches it to an email object for SendGrid, that's *all*].

My suspicion is that it's the blob receipt mechanism... but figured I'd ask here in case anyone can help out before spending any time digging deeper.  (it's not a *lot*, obviously, but it seems way more than is practical for such a small app - and I don't like the idea of costing my employer money in the event that I've just done something wrong)

Comment: I would recommend looking at storage analytics logs stored in `$logs` blob container. That should give you an idea about what is causing such large egress.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Gaurav.  I opened a log from 1am (ie when no staff are about) and it's just rammed full of lines like this:  1.0;2017-04-04T00:36:30.6299355Z;RenewBlobLease;Success;200;3;3;..... /Host.Functions.leaderboard-timer.Listener?comp=lease    The thing is, the blob which that is for is zero bytes...  (there are a few other similar blobs there, presumably these are used for synchronisation of function app hosts / timers etc.)... I don't see how that could be adding so much bandwidth.

Comment: Look for GetBlob operations in your logs. This is the operation which reads/downloads the blob and is probably causing the egress. Also look for ListBlobs operations. HTH.

Comment: Not a single one.  I picked an hour  (6am to 7am today).  The storage account egress chart shows a steady 12Mb output for blobs.... the logs show only those RenewBlobLease records.

Comment: (all diagnostics for the storage account are turned on, with retention set to 7 days)

Comment: Please look into Metrics tables (`$MetricsHourPrimaryTransactionsBlob` and `$MetricsMinutePrimaryTransactionsBlob`) and check the egress value there and compare it with the values in chart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139864/discussion-between-nathan-and-gaurav-mantri).

Comment: I have observed the same thing in quite a few projects. Whenever you write a blob trigger function it starts egress proportional to the size of total objects in storage. If I stop blob trigger function then this egress stops. Surprisingly my storage and bob trigger function are in the same zone/region. Even if a function is causing data read it should not cause data egress charges being in same zone. Not sure why its happening? It becomes very expensive when you write an blob trigger based image resize function on large image store.