# Azure Function App integration to Application Insights stops function monitoring tab

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I was very excited to see that the beta for [Azure Functions integration with Application Insights](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/04/06/azure-functions-application-insights/) was available.

Having enabled this as per the instructions in the link, I note that the "Monitor" section within the Azure Functions panel has stopped working (no new items being added since I made the change)

**Is that by design?**  (I can see the logic:  you're getting monitoring/timing information elsewhere)  I was just a bit surprised when I went to check how long a function was taking to run (while already in the Functions portal, it seemed the natural place to click...) and the monitor tab claimed the last time the function ran was a week ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think what you're running into is not related to the App Insights preview, but is instead caused by a recent issue, that you can read more about [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/394ef8a7-3f17-47c5-8443-17723c9a856e/invocation-logs-not-updating-in-portal?forum=AzureFunctions).

The fix should be deployed later this week. Also, see the workaround described in that thread (going to `https://<<functionappname>>.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions).`

Comment: If my app is running in beta (for the Applications Insights integration), will it get the fix? Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Yes, it will. With the fix, we'll actually remove the beta build so apps set to use it will fall back to non-beta (until a new beta is deployed later).

Comment: Thank you very much, David.  I don't suppose you have an opinion on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43202015/440704) of mine?